# Swagger @ApiModelProperty required field seems to get ignored (version 1.3.6)

Tags: java, swagger

Required field is ignored and doesn't get generated.
For example for property `a`

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient;

import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModel;
import com.wordnik.swagger.annotations.ApiModelProperty;

    @XmlRootElement
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    @ApiModel( value = "aaa")
    public class A implements IA
    {
        @ApiModelProperty( value = "bla", required = true )
        @XmlElement(name="a")
        private String a;


         public String getC() { return "kkk";};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you should switch the order of annotations!

instead of

```
        @ApiModelProperty( value = "bla", required = true )
        @XmlElement(name="a")
        private String a;
```

write

```
           @XmlElement(name="a")
           @ApiModelProperty( value = "bla", required = true )
            private String a;
```

Seems like a bug to me. Hopefully would be fixed in newer versions

Comment: The next major version of swagger-core is going to use a dedicated Jackson module for model building. However, if you don't open an issue, it's not very likely to get fixed.

Comment: Right on!. issue submitted, see https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/issues/788

Comment: Thanks for opening! That helps in pushing the product forward :)

Answer (score 0):

this is fixed in https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/commit/8c24ab4863e9e7bcd8a98add848b31af81ef77f2 which will be released in 1.3.12